# Rotation blocking move to center in map openlayers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers

**i have this function:**

```
  const resetMap = () => {
    setRotation(0);
    setZoom(8.3);
    onCoordinatesFocus([0,0]);
  }
```

The purpose of this function is to reset the maps rotation, zoom, and coordinates.

The zoom and rotation is in the state of the component (using the useState hook).

The `onCoordinatesFocus` function is kind of tricky. what happens there is that an event is fired (using pubsub), that the map component (that is located someplace else) is listening to using another function, which means the function `onCoordinatesFocus` is synchronous.

**The Problem:**

When the function `resetMap` is called once, the map resets ONLY zoom and rotation. The second time it's called, it resets just the location. Following this information I assumed that this is the order of the functions (`setRotation`, `setZoom`, `onCoordinateFocus`), so i tried to change it. This didn't work, which led me to believe that this happens because the animations for rotation and focus are clashing for some reason.

So i tried to add a setTimeout to (hopefully) wait for the rotation to end (although it is not animated). this is the new code:

```
  const resetMap = () => {
    setRotation(0);
    setZoom(8.3);
    setTimeout(() => {
        onCoordinatesFocus([0,0]);
    }, 1);
  }
```

This works, but it's a terrible solution. has anyone ever encountered this or has a better idea?

Comment: You can combine all three operations in a single animate call https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#animate